# Get function being used in error (from call)

Tags: r

I want to extract the name of the function being used from an error.  So if I had:

```
mean(letters)
"P" * 5
```

I'd want to extract `"mean.default"` and `"*"`.  I can get the call from the error as follows:

```
capturer <- function(x){
    tryCatch({
        x
    }, warning = function(w) {
        w
    }, error = function(e) {
        e
    })
}

capturer(mean(letters))$call
## mean.default(letters)

capturer("P" * 5)$call
## "P" * 5
```

But don't have a way to grab the function names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can grab the function name part with `$call[[1]]`. We could also add a `deparse` argument to add the option of having the result returned as a string.

```
capturer <- function(x, deparse = FALSE) {
    out <- tryCatch({
        x
    }, warning = function(w) {
        w$call[[1]]
    }, error = function(e) {
        e$call[[1]]
    })
    if(deparse) deparse(out) else out
}

## these return a call
capturer("P" * 5)
# `*`
capturer(mean(letters))
# mean.default

## these return a character
capturer("P" * 5, deparse = TRUE)
# [1] "*"
capturer(mean(letters), deparse = TRUE)
# [1] "mean.default"
```

Comment: Wait -- you're saying your answer is "NP" complete?  :-)

Comment: I was thinking more like "not problematic" ;)